# how to use WebView.platform = WebWebViewPlatform(); and WebView.platform = AndroidWebView(); in the same dart file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

I have a `flutter` application that needs to use `webview` in both the Android/Ios version and the Web version.

Essinatly to do this we need a code that separates the calls for every platform, and here is how I did it :

```
if (kIsWeb) {
  WebView.platform = WebWebViewPlatform();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "A**********************",
      appId: "**********************",
      messagingSenderId: "************",
      projectId: "water-maps-152c9",
    ),
  );
} else {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: const FirebaseOptions(
            apiKey: "*****************",
            appId: "1******************",
            messagingSenderId: "****************",
            projectId: "water-maps-152c9"));
    WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
  } else {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
  }
}
```

the problem is when it runs on a spicific platform as android, it fails to import the webview for web package, also if I didn't import it I get a `not defined` error at `WebView.platform = WebWebViewPlatform();`

so I have tried to import it like this :

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'package:webview_flutter_web/webview_flutter_web.dart';
```

but still am facing the `not defined` error as shown in the image:

[image]

Also when I try to import both as :

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart' ;
import 'package:webview_flutter_web/webview_flutter_web.dart';
```

it gives  me this error when I try to run the app on android

```
../src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_web-0.1.0+4/lib/webview_flutter_web.dart:70:9: Error: Type 'IFrameElement' not found.
  final IFrameElement _element;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_web-0.1.0+4/lib/webview_flutter_web.dart:274:10: Error: Type 'HttpRequest' not found.
  Future<HttpRequest> request(String url,
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
../src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_web-0.1.0+4/lib/webview_flutter_web.dart:281:21: Error: Type 'ProgressEvent' not found.
      void Function(ProgressEvent e)? onProgress}) {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:79:48: Error: Type 'html.EventListener' not found.
  external ui.VoidCallback addPopStateListener(html.EventListener fn);
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:193:3: Error: Type 'html.Location' not found.
  html.Location get _location => html.window.location;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:195:3: Error: Type 'html.History' not found.
  html.History get _history => html.window.history;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:198:28: Error: Type 'html.EventListener' not found.
  void addPopStateListener(html.EventListener fn) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:203:31: Error: Type 'html.EventListener' not found.
  void removePopStateListener(html.EventListener fn) {
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/utils.dart:7:7: Error: Type 'AnchorElement' not found.
final AnchorElement _urlParsingNode = AnchorElement();
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../src/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/utils.dart:20:7: Error: Type 'Element' not found.
final Element? _baseElement = document.querySelector('base');
      ^^^^^^^
../src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_web-0.1.0+4/lib/shims/dart_ui_fake.dart:19:26: Error: Type 'html.Element' not found.
      String viewTypeId, html.Element Function(int viewId) viewFactory) {
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_web-0.1.0+4/lib/webview_flutter_web.dart:23:25: Error: The method 'IFrameElement' isn't defined for the class 'WebWebViewPlatform'.
 - 'WebWebViewPlatform' is from 'package:webview_flutter_web/webview_flutter_web.dart' ('../src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_web-0.1.0+4/lib/webview_flutter_web.dart').
```

Comment: can you check the solution by removing if() condition in the import statement and importing both the statements?

Comment: Yes it gives an error in run time, as webview_flutter_web can't be imported in the android platform

Comment: since WebWebViewPlatform is used in web and AndroidWebView in android, it requires both the import statements. but that doesn't work as plugin "webview_flutter_web" is only for web. hence throws the error on android or ios. it would have worked if they had the same class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution from the [official docs](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_web#multi-platform-project-example):

**register_web_webview.dart**

```dart
void registerWebViewWebImplementation() {
  WebView.platform = WebWebViewPlatform();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      ...yourOptions
    ),
  );
}
```

**register_native_webview.dart**

```dart
void registerWebViewWebImplementation() {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: const FirebaseOptions(
          ...yourOptions
        )
    );
    WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
  } else {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'register_native_webview.dart'
    if (dart.library.html) 'register_web_webview.dart';

main() {
  registerWebViewWebImplementation();
}
```

Comment: Please be careful of using actual api keys in the example to answer the questions.